# How to select the best features for a drug discovery model?

Tags: machine-learning, biomaterials

I would like to build a regression model to predict a property of molecules not yet synthesized. I have calculated 5666 alvadesc descriptors for each SMILES in my experimental dataset, but comparing various models with LazyPredict I get poor R^2 values. I would like to know how to effectively select the minimum number of most relevant descriptors and if this can help me increase the value of R^2. I have tried using featurewiz with poor results.

Comment: You aren't giving much information as to the number of experimental data points or anything else about your task. You can definitely use things like LASSO to remove features from a regression model - 5666 descriptors IMHO isn't useful .. you undoubtedly have many fewer experimental data points, so the resulting model will be over-fit. But that won't necessarily improve your model (R^2 or RMSE). To do that, you need to have good data (i.e., little noise) and pick the *right* descriptors which may or may not be in your list.

Comment: Since there was no response to Geoff's comment and you haven't logged in since 9 months ago, we'll close this as "abandoned" but it can be reopened if you come back (just leave a comment)!